# Polarity change circuit - reverse polarity with only one relay

Tags: relay, reverse-polarity, diagram, polarity, drawing

I was looking for a polarity change circuit - (reverse polarity) with a single relay but I didn't find it or maybe I don't identify it, the only thing I've found are with two relays, do you have any kind of diagram to help me? The relay must have only 5 pins

Comment: "Relay must have only five pins" is a pretty strange constraint; are there others you haven't mentioned?

Comment: It is the requirement. From what I've searched I haven't found it, I don't know if it can really be done with a single 5-pin relay

Comment: A 5 pin relay will be SPDT - you need a DPDT relay or two SPDT relays because you will need to switch both positive and negative wires.  A DPDT relay will have 8 pins.  If you could find a relay dedicated to switching polarity (highly unlikely) it would have 6 pins: two inputs, two outputs, and two for the coil.

Comment: FYI, on this site, it is considered inappropriate to change a question in a way that invalidates an existing answer. Hacktastical and Dave Tweed both gave correct answers to your original question, and then you changed your question by adding a 5 pin requirement. Might I suggest that you avoid such modifications in the future.

Comment: It won't happen again.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this with a single DPDT relay. As follows ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgwM8RcbxiUINNzACQhIVGiCqMSEjDx4UyILSzYYJHPlQ2AJXBhBx7oT6moVmlW1WYCNgHMQeKpwlv+MvQHdv4Bie7kF+RiYoIoTukWFg0eCx8VTCcQmpGfhhqZbJidyQbP45CaImCYX+ZeClYh5xdaE5oYUuvEIofO2dsnoAzuFCCBL1KMNWEABmAIYANn0MBoNjEuZDEr021L0ORYESKwGHlUfj1SidDWqXGZeFAE608flPI2LucHvt1TTP1SffGhdQgiIFhbAg8BgiEiWIAyGWX4jOFsAAermIQjwfHUWPIFkEADFfAATAD0+gYADcGPcFgAdPoAZV8AEsAC4AYwAFmwgA)):

[image]

About '5 pins':

I'm pretty sure that there isn't a 5-pin relay that can do this in one unit, even though there are only 5 connections to the system (power, ground, coil, and 2 common pole outputs to the load, as shown.)

A SPDT relay *does* have 5 pins, but to do this kind of thing you'd need *two* of them, wired up as follows ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgwM8RcbxiUINNzACQhcFGiCw0BAjy4MCzGGzZhzPBJiQkYePCmRBaKrrBJdeqGwBK4MIMJ8X4vudpUrUKQjYA5iB4VJwSIfyC5mwA7pHgGOGhibZxrM58YIRUbpCx4NnuBVTCqcVC%20BXcpXlxpW5ZOR75pcQSooJtZR0gXT1h3WIDpQN5QbxCKHwTU555AM6OpgjtKSgrvhAAZgCGADbzDPZLQhtu6zq%20NN6%205nL5wxs9F4PL7WIoU6%20TfKWfzQAnWhZcAobg0EE9UJwfITHoQ95RWGQPgRbCEbgRWrA9pgnHBaJxdGYqgIgm2AAewWIQjwvzgtPImUEADEYgATAD0dgYADcGADDgAdeYAZRiAEsAC4AYwAFhwuDwUeTShF2lJBCw5AolCoMGoNJBCFodLB9IYGbpTFbYJZjDZsSMnFUfrZxir0srmdxokA)):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need a DPDT relay

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFpOvDm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> The relay must have only 5 pins

Given the requirement for only 5 pins on the relay, the only way I think that could work is if one pin for the coil is shared with one of the input supply voltages. The following is an example of how that could work. The box labelled `RLY1` has 5 external connections, and internally uses a DPDT relay:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffFwuq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where `SW11` controls the direction of the motor. I'm not sure if such 5-pin relays are actually manufactured.

Alternatively, if you can use two 5 pins relays see [Circuit for reversing a DC motor with two 5-pin relays](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/534479/101063)

Answer (score 0):

Like others mentioned, you need a DPDT relay (6-pin) provided you only have a single-ended power source. However, if you relax the latter provision, you can do it with a SPST (5-pin) relay:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmDYBb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Batteries could be other power source such as a (dual) rectified transformer. Relay power could be derived off of one or both polarity sources - the relay coil is isolated, so many configurations can control this without shorts.